# Running a JAR file as a background service in MAC OS

Tags: java, macos

I have created a java application and packaged as jar file.
My requirement is to run it as a background service in mac and this service should always run once installed( after the machine reboot too)
What would be the best way to do this

Comment: This should get you started: https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/adding-startup-scripts-to-launch-daemon-on-mac-os-x-sierra-10-12-6-7e0318c74de1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe append the command `nohup java -cp {your jar and dependencies} > /dev/null 2>&1 &` into the starting script `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.